# Scroll to anchor points only / override scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to implement a function where the page automatically scrolls to the next anchor point (up or down), similar to this page:
http://www.htc.com/ch-de/smartphones/htc-one-m9/

I already have the page somewhat set up (http://www.cubee.ch/wip) and most things run smoothly, but I could not figure out how to scroll to an anchor without a link/click :(

Thanks for any help!
Simon

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of plugin to make this. Here is one:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Comment: Well that was fast. I honestly didn't know what to search for exactly so I figured I just ask here :) Thanks man!

Comment: Yep, in fact fullPage.js will work much better than the HTC link you provided, as it will be using CSS3 transformations. (fallback to jQuery when not supported)